# Finding the biggest decimal for each integer in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array which holds each step in a tutorial and it's corresponding git commit sha. I want to select the final step in each chapter, which for the following example, corresponds to `1.1`, `2.5` and `3.4`. I am currently using a ***let...of*** iterator from Typescript to analyse the steps.

```
[1]     step: '3.4' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '52f7762e2a2d901b9d849e70679237fad8f0c05f',
[1]     step: '3.3' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '6ef63c21cd7f42fe5f190fb7bd5a7411528b944e',
[1]     step: '3.2' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: 'fe7bd36851672a24c0cd205f0763d52e6abfa6e1',
[1]     step: '3.1' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '13b948cc246b3c9b383c4be24ca0ba0a7c072e67',
[1]     step: '2.5' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '679bc61d53a59ad10c0398f2faecd7a4052689dc',
[1]     step: '2.4' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '76f57e963afb885fed48b1646fd50025269061ac',
[1]     step: '2.3' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: 'fd368fed4f47b9686e855b2a76e53dae5880ef69',
[1]     step: '2.2' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: 'a70e6f556640db53f1ef3acba28c42f582d45890',
[1]     step: '2.1' },
[1]   Commit {
[1]     hash: '95854756de842ff45ebbf9d3703cc7eff1557d5a',
[1]     step: '1.1' },
```

What is a neat way of doing this?

My current approach requires looping through all commits to find how many chapters there are, then filtering out all results with `step = chapter.x`. then finding the biggest x in that array. Then repeating for all chapters. This seems pretty clunky for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Couple questions for clarity - this is an array of Commits, correct? And is it safe to assume that the steps are sorted in descending order, as showing in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like underscore's [max()](http://underscorejs.org/#max), which would allow you to pass in the array, a function to test max, and returns the max value.

If this is for a project, or for some reason you can't use libraries, then a simple for loop would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This has a worst case complexity of linear, so the simplest way I can think to do it (in plain javascript) is:

```js
function maxChapters(commits) {
  var result = [];
  var recent = NaN;
  for (var i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
    var chapter = Math.floor(commits[i]['step']);
    if (chapter != recent) {
      result.push(commits[i]['step']);
      recent = chapter;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var commits = [{
  hash: '52f7762e2a2d901b9d849e70679237fad8f0c05f',
  step: '3.3' 
}, {
  hash: '6ef63c21cd7f42fe5f190fb7bd5a7411528b944e',
  step: '3.2' 
}, {
  hash: 'fe7bd36851672a24c0cd205f0763d52e6abfa6e1',
  step: '3.1' 
}, {
  hash: '13b948cc246b3c9b383c4be24ca0ba0a7c072e67',
  step: '2.5' 
}, {
  hash: '679bc61d53a59ad10c0398f2faecd7a4052689dc',
  step: '2.4' 
}, {
  hash: '76f57e963afb885fed48b1646fd50025269061ac',
  step: '2.3' 
},{
  hash: 'fd368fed4f47b9686e855b2a76e53dae5880ef69',
  step: '2.2' 
}, {
  hash: 'a70e6f556640db53f1ef3acba28c42f582d45890',
  step: '2.1' 
}, {
  hash: '95854756de842ff45ebbf9d3703cc7eff1557d5a',
  step: '1.1' 
}]

console.log(maxChapters(commits));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of approaches to this. I used the section number to offset my index in the array. This saves iteration over the array (one iteration per chapter instead of iterating every step), in exchange for having to do a bit more manipulation on each element (split the step string and cast the step to an int). Your mileage may vary. As with the other answers, this is a plain old javascript solution.

```js
//Only this function is the actual solution
function findLastSections(list) {
  var chapterEnds = [];
  var currCommit;
  var currIndex = 0;
  
  //Exit clause is when my index goes out-of-bounds.
  while(currIndex < list.length) {
    //I took the goal of trying to only iterate once per chapter.
    console.log('processing element: ' + currIndex);
    //get the last commit for the chapter
    currCommit = list[currIndex];
    //add its step to our return array.
    chapterEnds.unshift(currCommit.step);
    //split the step on the decimal, and parseInt so that I can do arithmetic on it. Add it to the index. This effectively shifts my position in the array by the length of the current chapter.
    currIndex += parseInt(currCommit.step.split('.')[1]);
  }
  console.log('returning: '); 
  console.log(chapterEnds);
  return chapterEnds;
}

//Everything below this line is just setup stuff to approximate your environment.

//Call to the function.
findLastSections(getCommitList());

 // Constructor function in place of Typescript class
function Commit(hash, step) {
  this.hash = hash;
  this.step = step;
}

function getCommitList() {
  //just did this to get it hoisted, so it's not crammed into the top of the snippet.
  return [
      new Commit (
     '52f7362e2a2d901b9d849e70679237fad8f0c05f',
     '3.4'),
      new Commit (
     '52f7762e2a2d901b9d849e70679237fad8f0c05f',
     '3.3'),
   new Commit (
     '6ef63c21cd7f42fe5f190fb7bd5a7411528b944e',
     '3.2'),
   new Commit (
     'fe7bd36851672a24c0cd205f0763d52e6abfa6e1',
     '3.1'),
   new Commit (
     '13b948cc246b3c9b383c4be24ca0ba0a7c072e67',
     '2.5'),
   new Commit (
     '679bc61d53a59ad10c0398f2faecd7a4052689dc',
     '2.4'),
   new Commit (
     '76f57e963afb885fed48b1646fd50025269061ac',
     '2.3'),
   new Commit (
     'fd368fed4f47b9686e855b2a76e53dae5880ef69',
     '2.2'),
   new Commit (
     'a70e6f556640db53f1ef3acba28c42f582d45890',
     '2.1'),
   new Commit (
     '95854756de842ff45ebbf9d3703cc7eff1557d5a',
     '1.1')
];
}
```